# Selenium C# Login Troubles on Test Server

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to selenium and am having some trouble logging into a test server. I installed Selenium (Webdriver & Support) on an AWS machine and can access the site manually. However, when I use Selenium to login, I am routed to the following URL: login.companyxyz.com/cgi/login with a 'Please contact your admin' message.

I know my code is correct because I've used it to navigate through logins on other pages that are not on a test server, such as gmail and bing.

I understand this is probably related to being in the Dev environment, but would the installation of Selenium Server fix this issue? If not, does anyone have any recommendations on how to get around it? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Try specifying a link as `https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@google.com/`

Comment: I used a different variation of the link provided above, which works! Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Include Username and Password in the link such as  https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@google.com/